# Replace substring inside double braces to a different string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, loops, substring, regexp-replace

Trying to replace substring inside double braces to a different string.
For example, let's say string

```
a = "In order to unlock this attempt, you must contact your {{teacher}}. When the attempt is unlocked by your {{teacher}}, we will notify you!"
```

I want to convert `a` to

```
"In order to unlock this attempt, you must contact your *coach*. When the attempt is unlocked by your *coach*, we will notify you!"
```

basically, replace "{{teach}}" to "Coach" in javascript. There are two or more to replace it. (problem)

Please how to replace using regular expressions (RegExp)it in javascript.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.prototype.replace()` method with regex. The replace method searches a string for a specified value, or a regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified values are replaced. Use the `g` modifier to replace all the occurrences of the specified value. The syntax of replace method `string.replace(searchValue, newValue)`

```js
const a = `In order to unlock this attempt, you must contact your {{teacher}}. When the attempt is unlocked by your {{teacher}}, we will notify you!`;
const ret = a.replace(/{{.*?}}/g, '*coach*');
console.log(ret);
```